# How to iterate over a FormArray containing formControl elements and non formControl elements without creating custom formControls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Sample .html file which populates a table with a formArray inside a formGroup. using the formArray I need to loop through formControl elements as well as non form control element as mentioned below.

```
<!-- edit: formgroup tag misspelled -->
<table [formGroup]="employeeTable">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>code</th>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>email</th>
     <th>department</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <ng-container formArrayName="employees">
     <ng-container *ngFor="let employee of employeeTable.get('employees').controls; let i = index">
       <tr [formGroup]="employee">
         <td>{{employee.controls['code']?.value}}</td>
         <td>{{employee.controls['name']?.value}}</td>
         <td>
           <input type="text" formControlName="email">
         </td>
         <td>
           <select formControlName="department" id="departmentSelection">
             <option *ngFor="let department of departments"></option>
           </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

related .ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'private-email-field',
  templateUrl: './private-email-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./private-email-field.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  employeeData: Array<any> = [
    {code: 1, name: 'John', email: '', department: ''},
    {code: 2, name: 'Jane', email: '', department: ''}
  ]

  employeeTable: FormGroup;
  employees: FormArray;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeTable = this.formBuilder.group({
      employees: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
    this.employees = this.employeeTable.controls['employees'] as FormArray;

    for(let data of this.employeeData) {
      const employee = this.formBuilder.group({
        code: [data.code],
        name: [data.name],
        email: [data.email, Validators.required],
        departmemt: [data.department]
      });
      this.employees.push(employee);
    }
  }

}
```

I just need to know that is there any way to loop through non formControl elements(eg: `<span>, <div>, <p>`) inside a formArray with formControl elements as the above example

Comment: a loop over FormArray.controls is like another loop you can use `let i=index` and, inside the loop `{{employedData[i].name}}`

Comment: thanks a lot, @Eliseo. Actually, it didn't come to my mind until you mention it. so far the problem is resolved from your suggestion